# How to bind Cmd+Space to Launchpad

Tags: keyboard, spotlight, launchpad

I'd like to bind <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> to open Launchpad because I [can't remove web suggestions from Spotlight](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/407010/271256).

In **Preferences** > **Keyboard** > **Shortcuts**, I've unchecked the box next to the Spotlight shortcut and changed the Launchpad shortcut to <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>. It tends to work for a bit, but eventually it just stops working and <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> does nothing. Is there a way to reliably bind <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> to open Launchpad instead of Spotlight?

Answer (score 1):

For me, it works well this way (on current latest macOS Monterey 12.3.1, MBA 10.1 - 2020, with the *Spotlight* button that replaced the traditional *Launcher* button on <kbd>F4</kbd>):

in **Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts**:

1. in left hand side menu: **Spotlight**, make sure you unchecked the shortcut <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd>
2. in left hand side menu: **Launchpad & Dock**, it should be initially set to `none`, click on it, type <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd>, make sure the checkbox is enabled

You should be done.

Double check you don't have any interfering shortcut in other menus, especially in **App Shorctuts**